# Multiply Define Labels when using \ifthispageodd and addmargin Environment

Tags: koma-script, warnings

I receive annoying warnings about multiply defined labels when I use `\ifthispageodd` and `addmargin` in the same document. I've made the following minimal test case to demonstrate this:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{scrextend}

\begin{document}
\ifthispageodd{odd}{even}
\begin{addmargin}{1pt}
Foo
\end{addmargin}
\end{document}
```

Starting with the second latex run, I get the following warning:

```
LaTeX Warning: Label `1' multiply defined.
```

Looking at the aux file, this warning comes as no surprise:

```
\relax 
\new@tpo@label{1}{1}
\new@tpo@label{1}{1}
```

Since it is only a warning, I could choose to ignore it but I'm wondering what's at fault here. It seems that the `addmargin` environment is the perpetrator, because when I remove it, the warning vanishes and if I add another one, I get two warnings (and three `\new@tpo@label` lines in the aux file).

But then again, when I remove the `\ifthispageodd` line, the `addmargin` environment stops emitting any `\new@tpo@label` lines into the aux file.

Am I using these commands wrong or is this a bug in KOMA/scrextend?

Comment: It's a bug. It does not result in wrong documents (but warnings). It is already listed in the [German bug list](http://www.komascript.de/release3.22) and will be fixed with the next [(pre)release >= 3.23.2602](http://www.komascript.de/current).

Comment: The link to the commit which provides the solution: https://sourceforge.net/p/koma-script/code/2602/

Comment: There is a second commit for this bug: https://sourceforge.net/p/koma-script/code/2603/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reporting this, the KOMA-Script author fixed the bug. Since [KOMA-Script prerelease 3.23.2605](http://www.komascript.de/current) the `aux` file of your example has only one `\new@tpo@label{1}{1}`. The warning about multiply defined labels does not longer occur.

Comment: Awesome! The commit you mentioned in your comment fixed it not only for this toy example but also for my actual document.

Comment: @hc_ Yes, reporting bugs can be a very useful thing. ;-)